# Java comparing lines in file with String

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, readline, filereader

I'm experiencing an strange issue with a file in Java...
I want to compare every line of this file with a string (host variable), but (I don't know why), the while loop is always comparing the first line of the file and ignores the second line, the third...

Here's the code:

```
fr = new FileReader (file);
inf = new BufferedReader(fr);
String l;
while ((l=inf.readLine()) != null) {
    if (host.contains(l))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Probably your host array contains the first line and it returns true

Comment: Are you sure? Try putting System.out.println(l) in while loop instead of if else statement

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You are finding the line in the host name - that's like finding a haystack in a needle - reverse the test
2. No matter the result of the condition, you return after testing it just once, so only the first line is tested

Instead, try this:

```
String l;
while ((l=inf.readLine()) != null)
    if (l.contains(host))
        return true;
return false;
```

Comment: Do we really need that **return false;** Will this do the samething which is in OP's question

Comment: @Octopus Yes, we do need the `return false;`. Without it you would get a compile error "missing return statement"

Comment: Ok, i think that should be after the *while* loop. In this case, *return false;* will get executed if line doesn't contain host. Am i right?

Comment: @Octopus It *is* after the loop (if you notice there are no braces). `return false` will get executed if *all* lines don't contain host.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `host.equals(l)`, or possibly `l.contains(host)`. It depends what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's only testing the first line in your file because of the if/else statement in the loop. Either branch results in a return thus stopping the rest of the file's contents from being processed.

Maybe you should return false only after you've reached the end of your file?

```
fr = new FileReader (file);
inf = new BufferedReader(fr);
String l;

while((l=inf.readLine())!=null){
    if (host.contains(l))
        return true;
}

return false;
```

Comment: @user2994057 Please accept this answer since it has solved your problem! so, that passers by can take this the best one in the list

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are looking for the host string in the file. You could possible do it like this.

```
public boolean contains(Reader in, String word) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader inf = new BufferedReader(in);
    String l;
    boolean found = false;
    while((l=inf.readLine())!=null){
        if (l.contains(word)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```